# Docstrings are invalid after upgrading packages

Tags: package

When I upgrade packages in the `M-x list-packages` menu, the docstrings and locations of the function definitions are invalid so that `describe-function` gives an error and `find-function` does not jump to the correct file.  For example, running `M-x describe-function` on slime yields a help buffer that shows the following:

```
slime is an interactive compiled Lisp function.

(slime &optional ARG1 ARG2)

Cannot open doc string file "/home/user/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20150501.137/slime.elc"

[back]
```

Running `M-x find-function` on slime yields the following (I have debug-on-error set to t):

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Can't find library /home/user/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20150501.137/slime.el")
  signal(error ("Can't find library /home/user/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20150501.137/slime.el"))
  error("Can't find library %s" "/home/user/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20150501.137/slime.el")
  find-library-name("/home/user/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20150501.137/slime.el")
  find-function-search-for-symbol(slime nil "/home/user/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20150501.137/slime.elc")
  find-function-noselect(slime)
  find-definition-noselect(slime nil)
  find-function-do-it(slime nil switch-to-buffer)
  find-function(slime)
  call-interactively(find-function nil nil)
  command-execute(find-function)
```

Is there a way to fix this that doesn't require restarting Emacs?

Comment: Probably. But could you please file a bug for it? It's something that should be fixed in master anyway.

Comment: @Malabarba I'll do that but in the meantime I'm still interested in a solution.

Comment: Your description of the problem is not very good. "*stop working*" and "*do not work as they should*" mean what, exactly? This risks being closed as unclear or too broad, so you might want to try to specify the problem a bit better. What do you see, and what did you expect to see instead?

Comment: @Drew It should be clear what the problem is when running the offending functions after an upgrade.  However, my latest edit should remove any ambiguity.

Comment: It is now over two years since this question was asked. I could not find an emacs bug on it and it is still not fixed. I submitted a bug report a week ago. Still waiting for response. I hope this gets fixes as it the main reason for me  to restart my emacs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution is to load that package again: `M-x load-library <package>`

I have seen the same problem. I believe it is because the docstrings etc. are "pointing" to the old version of the code which was deleted when you upgraded the package. By loading it you reset these links.

Comment: Perhaps it is even best to run `unload-feature` on the package after an upgrade, and then run `load-library` to get things extra clean.

Comment: Restarting Emacs also worked for me.